# How should I evaluate the flux?

Tags: vector-analysis, surface-integrals, divergence-theorem

I have the following vector field

$F= \frac{11x}{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}} \vec{i} + \frac{11y}{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}} \vec{j} + \frac{11z}{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}} \vec{k}$

I need to calculate the flux, $\iint_{S} F \cdot \vec{n}\ \text{dS}$, through the surface $S: x^2+y^2+z^2 = 16$ (sphere). As $F$ has a singularity at origin, I can't use the Divergent Theorem (right?). So I try to calculate using the surface integral of a vector field, $\iint_{S} F \cdot \vec{n}\ \text{dS} = \iint_{D} F(\mathbf{r}(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v})) \cdot (\mathbf{r_u} \times \mathbf{r_v})\ \text{dA}$.

I've used the parametric representation $\mathbf{r}(\phi,\theta) = (4 \sin\phi\cos\theta, 4 \sin\phi\sin\theta, 4 \cos\phi)$. When I perform $F(\mathbf{r}(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v})) \cdot (\mathbf{r_u} \times \mathbf{r_v})$, I'm getting 0. With this result, my flux would be 0, but according to my teacher answer, the flux is $44\pi$. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Arthur, I've changed my question to be clearer.

Comment: $\boldsymbol F$ and $d\boldsymbol S$ are collinear, clearly the dot product cannot be zero. We have $\boldsymbol F = 11 \boldsymbol r/r^3$ and $\hat {\boldsymbol n} = \boldsymbol r/r$, so
$$\iint_{r = R} \boldsymbol F \cdot d\boldsymbol S =
\frac {11} {R^2} \iint_{r = R} dS.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spherical coordinates,

$x = r \cos \theta \sin \phi, y = r \sin \theta \sin \phi, z = r\cos \phi$

$F = \frac{11x}{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}} \vec{i} + \frac{11y}{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}} \vec{j} + \frac{11z}{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}} \vec{k}$

$F = (\frac{11\cos \theta \sin \phi}{r^2}, \frac{11\sin \theta \sin \phi}{r^2}, \frac{11 \cos \phi}{r^2})$

Outward normal vector $\hat{n} = \frac{1}{r}(x, y, z) = (\cos \theta \sin \phi \, , \sin \theta \sin \phi \, , \cos \phi \,)$

In spherical coordinates, $dS = r^2 \sin \phi \ d \theta \, d \phi$

$Flux = \displaystyle \iint_S \vec{F} \cdot \hat{n} dS$

$\vec{F} \cdot \hat{n} dS = (\frac{11\cos \theta \sin \phi}{r^2}, \frac{11\sin \theta \sin \phi}{r^2}, \frac{11 \cos \phi}{r^2}) \cdot (\cos \theta \sin \phi \, , \sin \theta \sin \phi \, , \cos \phi \,) dS$

$ = 11(\cos^2 \theta \sin^2 \phi + \sin^2 \theta \sin^2 \phi + \cos^2 \phi) \sin \phi d\theta d\phi = 11 \sin \phi d\theta d\phi$

So, $Flux = \displaystyle \iint_S \vec{F} \cdot \hat{n} dS = 11 \int_0^\pi \int_0^{2\pi}\sin \phi d\theta d\phi = \fbox {44 $\pi$}$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you, please, explain why $\hat{n} = \frac{1}{r}(x, y, z)$?

Comment: An outward normal vector to a spherical surface with center at the origin will be $(x-0)i + (y-0)j + (z-0)k$ where $(x, y, z)$ is point on the surface of the sphere. To find unit normal vector, you need to divide it by its magnitude which is $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} = r$

Comment: I got it, thank you. Regarding my approach, why am I getting the flux equals to 0? Isn't it right what I'm doing?

Comment: @Magela you should not get dot product as zero. What is the normal vector you are getting? That must be wrong.

Comment: $(r_u \times r_v)$ should come to $16 (\sin^2\phi \cos \theta, \sin^2 \phi \sin \theta, \sin \phi \cos \phi)$

Comment: Yes, you're right. I found my mistake. About continuity, $F$ isn't continuous at (0, 0, 0). Doesn't this matter in this case?

Comment: Yes it does matter and we cannot apply Divergence theorem to find flux.

Comment: Right. We cannot apply Divergent theorem for this reason, but why can we calculate the surface integral so?

Comment: Surface integral is directly calculating flux over the _surface_ of the sphere so it works. Divergence theorem says this surface integral (flux) is same as volume integral of the divergence _inside_ the surface. Now you can see why continuity issue at origin matters when we want to use  divergence theorem method to find flux.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real need to use divergence theorem here. The polar coordinate representation should do.

\begin{gather*}
Transferring\ to\ polar\ coordinates,\ we\ see\ that\ \\
F( r) =\frac{11}{r^{2}} \ \\
Since\ the\ field\ is\ spherically\ symmetric,\ \\
we\ can\ directly\ calculate\ the\ flux\ as\ \\
\oint F( r) dr=\int 4\pi r^{2} F( r) dr=\int 44\pi dr=176\pi \\
\\
\end{gather*}
I am not sure whether your final answer is correct, because that would mean that the radius of the sphere should be 1 in that case.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'm afraid that I did not understand how you can get $F(r) = \frac{11}{r^2}$. Did you see that the vector field has the coordinates $ F = \left\{ \frac{11x}{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}},\frac{11y}{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}},\frac{11z}{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}} \right\}$